# jQuery turn integer into percentage through HTML input

Tags: jquery, html, math, integer, percentage

Passing percentage into an HTML input. I'd like to use a whole number, such as `2` to signify `0.02`. How can I achieve this with the following code?

**jQuery:**

```
function percentage_output() {

    var rate = $('#rate').val();

    $('#output').html(rate);

};
$('input').on('blur', percentage_output);
```

**HTML:**

```
<input id="rate" type="number">

<div>
    Output: <span id="output"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my goodness you're in trouble, you might have have to actually use math..

```
var rate = $('#rate').val() / 100;
```

Comment: I didn't think to do that within the variable. Math isn't the issue, my newness to the ways of javascript seems to be. Thanks! (setting as answer in 4 minutes, will remove this edit message)

Comment: variables just hold information. you could just as easily do `$('#output').html($('#rate').val() / 100);` - if this helps please hit the check mark :)

Comment: I believe I was getting stuck on the idea that the integer had to parse through the input, use the variable, then convert to a percentage. I was wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexanderGraham - welcome to the world of programming :p

Comment: Been a front-ender for a long time, but now that I'm exploring more php, javascript, getting into node, gulp, angular ... *--head exploding gif here--*

Answer (score 0):

why cant u do this

```
var rate = parseInt($('#rate').val());
var rateInPorcentage = rate/100;
$('#output').html(rateInPorcentage);
```

Havent tested this but i asuming it works